# Get list of files from Google Drive v2 in PHP

Tags: php, list, file, google-drive-api

I am trying to get a list of files on my Google drive using the `v2 PHP API`. I have managed to create folders and upload files, but this has me stumped. I am using a Service Account.

I am basing my code on https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list#php which I guess should work! After the line

```
$files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
```

I do a `print_r` and get an object containing roughly what I expect. I can extract the information I need by poking around inside the object, but it seems that I should be able to do (from the same example):

```
$files->getItems()
```

However this leads to this error:

```
Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_FileList::getItems()
```

Comment: You should consider switching to Google Drive v3.

Answer (score 3):

About the error of `Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_FileList::getItems()`, I thought that from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63803581), you might use Drive API v3. As the confirmation, when `$files->getItems()` is used with Drive API v3, I could confirm that the same error message with you is shown. So please modify as follows and test it again.

#### From:

```
$files->getItems()
```

#### To:

```
$files->getFiles()
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: I appreciate that life would be easier on v3 but there are PHP constraints that I have to live with for now.
Anyway I just browse the object and extract what I need with a simple function so not really a big issue any more.

Comment: @Dave Torr Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I couldn't understand whether my proposal could remove your error of `Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_FileList::getItems()`. And if the error didn't resolve, can I ask you about your current issue? I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: I have removed the call because I can get the information I need from the files object that is returned. I cannot at the moment move to v3 but it is on my plans